# I'm having an error when changing the screen, the first button works, but the others don't. There is no error in andoid studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm having an error when changing the screen, the first button works, but the others don't. There is no error in andoid studio.

```
package com.example.copadomundo

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import com.example.copadomundo.databinding.ActivityMainBinding


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        val view = binding.root
        setContentView(view)

        binding.buttonBrazil.setOnClickListener{
            val intent = Intent(this, CampoBrasil::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
        binding.buttonServia.setOnClickListener{
            val intent = Intent(this, CampoServia::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
       
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should probably check your `AndroidManifest.xml` to verify if the activities are declared there.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="<your package name>">

    <application>
        <activity
            android:name="<your Activity>"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```